# Sort NSArray of NSDictionary using value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`. In the `NSDictionary` I have an element called 'rowID' which is saved as an `NSString`. However, everything saved in it is a number even though they saved as a string.

I would like to know how to sort the array based on this value but in terms of sorting 1-100. Currently, when I sort it 10 comes first when it should be 1-10.

This is how I am sorting:

```
NSArray *tempSortedItemsArray = [itemArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                                     @[[NSSortDescriptor
                                        sortDescriptorWithKey:@"rowID" ascending:YES]]];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :-

```
NSArray *aSortedArray = [itemArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSMutableDictionary *obj1,NSMutableDictionary *obj2) {
    NSString *num1 =[obj1 objectForKey:@"rowID"];
    NSString *num2 =[obj2 objectForKey:@"rowID"];
    return (NSComparisonResult) [num1 compare:num2 options:(NSNumericSearch)];
}];
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP has stated that the rowIDs are `NSString` objects, not `NSNumber` objects. This will end up doing the same incorrect string comparison.

Comment: it worked fine at my end test it if you find incorrect result then i will delete my answer

Comment: It's correct if the `rowID` values are actually `NSNumber` objects but the OP has `NSString` objects.

Comment: this worked for me... the values are NSStrings... why is it working for me?

Comment: because of Numeric Search thats what you wanted..

Answer (score 2):

You can get numeric sorting by following this code:-

```
NSMutableArray *tmpAr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tmpDict setObject:@"name" forKey:@"number5"];
[tmpDict setObject:@"5" forKey:@"id"];
[tmpAr addObject:tmpDict];

tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tmpDict setObject:@"name" forKey:@"number3"];
[tmpDict setObject:@"3" forKey:@"id"];
[tmpAr addObject:tmpDict];

tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tmpDict setObject:@"name" forKey:@"number2"];
[tmpDict setObject:@"2" forKey:@"id"];
[tmpAr addObject:tmpDict];

tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tmpDict setObject:@"name" forKey:@"number1"];
[tmpDict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"id"];
[tmpAr addObject:tmpDict];

tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tmpDict setObject:@"name" forKey:@"number4"];
[tmpDict setObject:@"4" forKey:@"id"];
[tmpAr addObject:tmpDict];

tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tmpDict setObject:@"name" forKey:@"number25"];
[tmpDict setObject:@"25" forKey:@"id"];
[tmpAr addObject:tmpDict];

tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tmpDict setObject:@"name" forKey:@"number10"];
[tmpDict setObject:@"10" forKey:@"id"];
[tmpAr addObject:tmpDict];

tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tmpDict setObject:@"name" forKey:@"number7"];
[tmpDict setObject:@"7" forKey:@"id"];
[tmpAr addObject:tmpDict];

NSLog(@"tmpar1 = %@",tmpAr);

[tmpAr sortUsingComparator:
 ^(id obj1, id obj2)
 {
     NSInteger value1 = [[obj1 objectForKey: @"id"] intValue];
     NSInteger value2 = [[obj2 objectForKey: @"id"] intValue];
     if (value1 > value2)
     {
         return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
     }

     if (value1 < value2)
     {
         return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
     }
     return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
 }];

NSLog(@"tmpar2 = %@",tmpAr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create your sort descriptor with `initWithKey:ascending:selector:` or `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:` you can specify a selector used to compare objects.

Now the problem is which selector to pass. Well, you can create a Category on NSString implementing a custom sort function that sorts based on the numeric value of the string. Remember that from the documents:

> The selector must specify a method implemented by the value of the
>   property identified by keyPath. The selector used for the comparison
>   is passed a single parameter, the object to compare against self, and
>   must return the appropriate NSComparisonResult constant. The selector
>   must have the same method signature as:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)localizedCompare:(NSString *)aString
```

> The object at the specified property key, relative to each object in
>   the collection, must implement the compare selector used to create the
>   sort descriptor. If no custom selector was specified, the objects must
>   implement compare.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :-

```
NSDictionary *row1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"rowId",nil];
NSDictionary *row2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2",@"rowId",nil];
NSDictionary *row3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"3",@"rowId",nil];

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:row1,row2,row3,nil];

NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"rowId" ascending:YES];
[arr sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:desc]];

// before sort
NSLog(@"Before %@",arr);
[arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *item1, NSDictionary *item2) {
    NSString *first = [item1 objectForKey:@"rowId"];
    NSString *second = [item2 objectForKey:@"rowId"];
    return [first compare:second options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
// After sort
NSLog(@"After %@",arr);
```

Comment: How is this different of what the user is already doing???

Comment: The update is still incorrect. This does an alphabetic sort instead of the desired numeric sort.